# C Language Increment(I Think)

Tags: c, increment, decrement

I'll start by saying it's a homework thing, but its got nothing to do with me learning C.
We are tasked to implement solutions to the Reader/Writer conflict using Semaphores and priority. Doing so in Java for the class.

The book we are working with, however uses C(I think) to handle their code examples. I'm not all that familiar with standard C and I can't figure out how to search existing literature for the answer I seek.

In the code:

```
semaphore x=1,wsem=1;
int readcount;

void reader()
{
    While (true){
    semWait(x);
    readCount++;
    if(readcount==1)
    {
        semWait(wsem);
    }
    semSignal(x);
    READUNIT();
    semWait(x);
    readcount; /* <--- the questionable command */
    if(readcount==0)
    {
        semSignal(wsem)
    }
    semSignal(x);
    }
}
```

The line I have "starred" doesn't make any apparent sense. I appears to be simply stating or declaring the name of the variable. Is this some form of decrement I've never seen, or does this do something else? It seems like I'd be able to find it in some C-guide somewhere, but I haven't a clue what it's doing so I don't really know how to ASK what it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable name followed by a semicolon is a complete legal statement in C, but it does nothing. The form is rarely used, although it can be useful to suppress unused-variable warnings in some compilers.

From context, what it was probably supposed to be is `readcount--;`. That's the C decrement operator, undoing the `readcount++` above.

Does your source also have the (erroneous) capital-W `While` and inconsistent spellings of `readcount`? If so, that's several bad typos in one short example and you should be suspicious of everything else in the book.

Comment: Indeed, java solutions I've looked up using similar code decrement the read counter at that line. I just wanted to be sure, as the usage of the x semaphore is puzzling and not being sure of the code around it doesn't clear it up.
I'd just like to see if there's some weird shortcut-decrement going on as the book uses this....whatever it is, repeatedly.
The While was me, I was typing from book to screen and failed to see the capitalization when I did it.

Comment: Let me just add that a somewhat more descriptive form to ignore a value (either an unused variable or a function result) is to cast it to void: `(void)foo;` or `(void)bar();`.

Comment: There's no such shortcut in C; if the book is using bare variable names as statements routinely, I would guess that there was a typesetting process error, like `--` being converted to an em dash in one stage, then removed from the listings (because em dashes don't belong in C source) in another stage. Again, bad book.